# store/generate <select> options for later use?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some javascript that generates a large list of `<select>` options (`<option>`) elements on the fly.  And I need to be able to switch between 3 or 4 different generated lists based on the value of another `<select>` menu using an "onchange" event.

Is there a way I can store multiple lists of options and then just redirect the select object to the appropriate list as necessary?

Right now, I have to delete all the options and re-add them one at a time.  That seems horribly wasteful / time consuming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the different lists of options as simple arrays, then do something like this:

```
function setThisSelect(selectId, optionsArray){
    var sel = document.getElementById(selectId);
    sel.options.length = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < optionsArray.length; i++)
        sel.options.add(optionsArray[i]);
}
```

And here's how you might create your options:

```
    var optionsArr1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var op = document.createElement("option");
        op.value = i;
        op.text = i;
        optionsArr1.push(op);
    }
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dGpUZ/):

But if you're wanting to do a lot of this, it might get tedious pretty quickly.  This might be something a library like jQuery can help accomplish with a lot less code.

Comment: I suppose that's a significant improvement over recreating the option array each time.  But there's no standard way to do it without pushing the options one at time?

Comment: This looks like the path of least resistance for now.

Answer (score 1):

DocumentFragments might be what you're looking for.

http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/

> Furthermore, various operations -- such as inserting nodes as children
>   of another Node -- may take DocumentFragment objects as arguments;
>   this results in all the child nodes of the DocumentFragment being
>   moved to the child list of this node.

Comment: I'm intrigued, however due to my noob status w/ javascript & DOM manipulation I'm having trouble figuring out how to replace (rather than append to) the content of an element with a fragment's content.

Comment: I played with it for about 15 minutes and couldn't get it working either. So, at this point, it has promise, but not sure it's what you need.

Comment: I just managed to remove all the children using this method: http://matthom.com/archive/2007/05/03/removing-all-child-nodes-from-an-element.   It works, but not sure how it stacks up against `sel.options.length=0;`.  I might do some benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a perfect case for jQuery templates.
You can store all data for every case as json. Create a template of <select> element. When user changed some parameter you'll pick a proper json and bind to a template. You can find examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/).